# WP пересчет размера блока слайдера

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

Wordpress. Плагин Ultimate Responsive Slider
Пример страницы - http://lavds-wordpress.tw1.ru/test2/

Есть таблица, при нажатие на ссылку неактивный див становится видимым.
В нем находится слайдер. Он не отображается верно. Я правильно понимаю что нужно при нажатии на ссылку вкладки пересчитать (после задержки?) размеры окна? блока? с помощью jquery.

Беру клик по ссылке, а что дальше не знаю.

```
jQuery(".resize-tab").click(function() {
  ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам порекомендовал использовать другой метод - не использовать скрипты для смены вкладок, а использовать, допустим, radio-кнопки и css. И выводить картинки не плагином, а обычным слайдером, типа [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), записывая их с помощью кастомных полей. Я, при необходимости, делаю так - проблем ноль.